# How to filter and merge two java lists

Tags: java, json, lambda

I need to join two lists, but I need to make a filter, I use lambda but I can't evolve

list1:

```
        {
            "idMateria": 9,
            "idUsuario": 7,
            "materia": "portugues",
            "descricao": "desc"
        },
        {
            "idMateria": 10,
            "idUsuario": 7,
            "materia": "matematica",
            "descricao": "desc"
        }
        {
            "idMateria": 10,
            "idUsuario": 4,
            "materia": "matematica",
            "descricao": "desc"
        }
```

list2:

```
    {
        "idNotaMateria": 6,
        "idMateria": 234,
        "idUsuario": 7,
        "notaMateria": 432.0,

    },
    {
        "idNotaMateria": 1,
        "idMateria": 10,
        "idUsuario": 7,
        "notaMateria": 4.0,

    },
    {
        "idNotaMateria": 1,
        "idMateria": 10,
        "idUsuario": 7,
        "notaMateria": 4.0,

    }
```

result:

```
{
    "idNotaMateria": 1,
    "idMateria": 10,
    "idUsuario": 7,
    "notaMateria": 4.0,
     "materia": "matematica"

},
{
    "idNotaMateria": 1,
    "idMateria": 10,
    "idUsuario": 7,
    "notaMateria": 4.0,
     "materia": "matematica"

}
```

it is necessary to create a new list by filtering by the idusuario field and merging the columns, until now they can only reproduce the separate lists

List notasMaterias = repository.findAll(Sort.by("dataNota").descending());
List materias = materiaRepository.findAll();

```
List<NotasMateria> filter1 =
        notasMaterias.stream()
                .filter(t -> t.getIdUsuario()== idusuario)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Materia> filter2  = materias.stream()
        .filter(t ->t.getIdUsuario().equals(idusuario) )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: what your filter and merge rules？

Comment: filter lists with the same field idUsuario and Materia and add the materia field from list2,please help me

Answer (score 0):

**Approach:**

- We will filter `materias` with `idusuario` and then create a map of `idmateria` to `materias`
- Next we will filter `nonmaterias` stream with `idusuario` and also filter based on `idMateria` comparing the earlier map.

**Code:**

```
public List<Merged> filterAndMerge(List<Materia> materiaList, List<NonMateria> nonMateriaList, int idusuario) {
    Map<Integer, Materia> materiaMap = materiaList.stream()
                                                  .filter(m -> m.getIdUsuario() == idusuario)
                                                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Materia::getIdMateria, m -> m));

    return nonMateriaList.stream()
                         .filter(nm -> nm.getIdUsuario() == idusuario)
                         .filter(nm -> materiaMap.containsKey(nm.getIdMateria()))
                         .map(nm -> new Merged(nm, materiaMap.get(nm.getIdMateria())
                                                                        .getMateria()))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

*Note:*
I have created `Merged` class consisting of all fields required in the result. It contains a constructor that takes `class NonMateria` and string `materia` as parameters.

```
public Merged(NonMateria nm, String materia) {
    this.idNotaMateria = nm.getIdNotaMateria();
    this.idMateria = nm.getIdMateria();
    this.idUsuario = nm.getIdUsuario();
    this.notaMateria = nm.getNotaMateria();
    this.materia = materia;
}
```